# R: Sum two columns from different time series data frames of unequal length, indexing by timeStamp

Tags: r, sum, time-series, mutate

I have the following dataframes:

```
df1 <-
    setNames(data.frame(
        as.POSIXct(
            c(
            "2022-07-29 00:00:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:00:05",
            "2022-07-29 00:05:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:05:05",
            "2022-07-29 00:10:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:15:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:20:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:20:05"
            )),
        c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
    ),
    c("timeStamp", "value1"))
df2 <-
    setNames(data.frame(
        as.POSIXct(
            c(
            "2022-07-29 00:00:05",
            "2022-07-29 00:05:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:05:03",
            "2022-07-29 00:10:02",
            "2022-07-29 00:20:05"
            )),
        c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    ),
    c("timeStamp", "value1"))
```

What I want to do, in a new column in df1, is sum the two "value1" columns together when they are from the same time stamp, and if there is only one value at a certain time stamp, then take that value. so the result should be:

```
df_new <- df1 %>% mutate(total = df1$value1 + df2$value1)
...
```

so total would have 10 values. however I always get an error: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Please note I cannot use rbind, these values are cumulative, so to use rbind and then cumsum the total column would be incorrect

Comment: What I have been doing, is to simply cut off the data from the longer data.frame using df1[-c(6:8),] for example, and then i am able to add them together. This is very tedious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df1 |> 
    full_join(df2, by = "timeStamp") |>
    group_by(timeStamp) |> 
    mutate(total = sum(value1.x, value1.y, na.rm = TRUE))


# Groups:   timeStamp [10]
   timeStamp           value1.x value1.y total
   <dttm>                 <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2022-07-29 00:00:00        1       NA     1
 2 2022-07-29 00:00:05        2        1     3
 3 2022-07-29 00:05:00        3        2     5
 4 2022-07-29 00:05:05        4       NA     4
 5 2022-07-29 00:10:00        5       NA     5
 6 2022-07-29 00:15:00        6       NA     6
 7 2022-07-29 00:20:00        7       NA     7
 8 2022-07-29 00:20:05        8        5    13
 9 2022-07-29 00:05:03       NA        3     3
10 2022-07-29 00:10:02       NA        4     4
```

Addendum:

```
df1 |> 
    full_join(df2, by = "timeStamp") |>
    group_by(timeStamp) |> 
    mutate(total = sum(value1.x, value1.y, na.rm = TRUE)) |> 
    ungroup() |> 
    mutate(ctotal = total + lag(total, 1),
           ctotal = ifelse(is.na(ctotal), total, ctotal))


   timeStamp           value1.x value1.y total ctotal
   <dttm>                 <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2022-07-29 00:00:00        1       NA     1      1
 2 2022-07-29 00:00:05        2        1     3      4
 3 2022-07-29 00:05:00        3        2     5      8
 4 2022-07-29 00:05:05        4       NA     4      9
 5 2022-07-29 00:10:00        5       NA     5      9
 6 2022-07-29 00:15:00        6       NA     6     11
 7 2022-07-29 00:20:00        7       NA     7     13
 8 2022-07-29 00:20:05        8        5    13     20
 9 2022-07-29 00:05:03       NA        3     3     16
10 2022-07-29 00:10:02       NA        4     4      7
```

Comment: Precisely what I'm looking for, but with one caveat. How would i adjust the total column here to add to the most recent total? i.e., total[2] should be the sum of row 2, added to  total[1], so it would be 4, and so on?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but I edited with an addendum. Let me know if that's what you're after :)

Comment: I think your response should work, but I am a bit confused. is |> r language? do you mean %>%? When I copy your answer with %>%, howver, I seem to be getting the entire sum of the value1.x and value1.y columns, copied for every row down the dataframe

Comment: |> is the new base pipe for R (see e.g., https://r4ds.hadley.nz/workflow-pipes.html). In this case they are interchangeable and you can use whichever. Given that you have R 4.1 (or later)

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you only want it to sum with the adjacent row? That should be done with the new addendum.